# Creating direct CLIs with python

Tags: python, bash, shell, terminal, command-line-interface

I would like to create a direct CLI command with python (not married to python). I see many python CLI tools, but the result requires calls that look like

```
$ python program.py command argument
```

I would like to create command line tools that function like `pip` or `curl` so that my command calls can be executed in terminal like

`$ program command argument` much like `$ pip install packagename`
How could I do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what operating system are you on?

Comment: Answers from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/828737/run-python-scripts-without-explicitly-invoking-python) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1112867/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-a-c-shell-without-specifying-whole-path) questions could be helpful.

Comment: @Roy2012 I'm on a mac.

Comment: @OlvinRoght thanks for the research. I was hoping to do this in a way that actually creates a command line application that can have defined commands, like pip. I could see leaving the extension off the name of the script, putting the script in the users path when installed, including python in the shebang, and allowing the script to accept function names as arguments. That seems janky though. What do you think?

Comment: If you're on mac, all you need to do is add a shebang to your script, change the mode to executable (chmod +x my_file), remove the .py extension, and add it to your path. Is that what you're looking for? Or are you looking for a more wholistic solution?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is to both put the script in the `$PATH` variable and to add a shebang to the script specifying it is should be run with python. Additionally, the script needs to be marked as an executable which can be done one of two ways. You can either manually make it an uncompiled (open source) executable with `sudo chmod +x`, or you can use `pyinstall` to create a closed source executable.